# The "ValidatePackage" task was not given a value for the required parameter "ProjectService" when deploying in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, error

I have a SharePoint feature built with Visual Stuido 2010. Everything has been working on my project untill I changed the Site URL for the SharePoint project. Now when I goto deploy my solution I get the error:

> The "ValidatePackage" task was not given a value for the required
>   parameter "ProjectService".

Ok great I need to find the ValidatePackage task that is called on deploy and fix the ProjectService parameter.

Where would I go to find the ValidatePackage task? I have search in Visual Studio but no luck. I aslo tried searching in files but again nothing was found.

**Update**
If I create a new solution. Createa blank project and select deploy I get the same error.

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets

Seems to have 18 warnings in it, such as:

> Warning   6   The element 'ItemGroup' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003' has invalid
>   child element 'Package' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'. List of
>   possible elements expected: 'Item, Reference, COMReference,
>   COMFileReference, Xdcmake, Bscmake, ClCompile, ClInclude, Midl,
>   ResourceCompile, PreLinkEvent, CustomBuildStep, Manifest,
>   ProjectConfiguration, NativeReference, ProjectReference, Compile,
>   EmbeddedResource, Content, Page, Resource, ApplicationDefinition,
>   None, BaseApplicationManifest, Folder, Import, Service, WebReferences,
>   WebReferenceUrl, FileAssociation, BootstrapperFile, PublishFile,
>   CodeAnalysisDependentAssemblyPaths, CodeAnalysisDictionary,
>   CodeAnalysisImport, Link, ResourceCompile, PreBuildEvent,
>   PostBuildEvent' in namespace
>   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003'.    C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\SharePointTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SharePoint.targets  181 8   Miscellaneous
>   Files

**Update**

I tried repearing VS2010 and the error remains.

**Update**

If I use CKSDev I can deploy OK. It is jsut the built in Visual Studio 2010 deploy that is failing. Also means that pressing f5 for debugging does not work.

**Update**

I tried removing VS2010 and reinstalling but the error remained on a reinstall. I dont think the VS uninstall removes everything as it rememberd my extension details :(

Comment: does it work if you revert back the change (if yes, what's the url)? same environment before and after above error?

Comment: Looks to be enviomental as resotring the files fro msource control gives the same errors.

Comment: the warning you see when you open .targets file may not help you because I get similar warnings as well and my environment is working fine. Did you try moving source code to some other dev env and see if it builds?

Comment: Glad you get the warnings as well. Don't have another enviroment that I can get my hands on at the moment. Will see what else I can work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Visual Studio 2010 Uninstall Utility](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/vs2010uninstall) I remvoed VS2010 from my machine. I then made sure SP1 was removed as well.

I reinstalled VS2010 and then applied SP1. I then hit the deploy button on the same code as before and it worked.